# Converting from Viewport Coordinates to [-1,1]^2 Vertex [OpenGL]

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, viewport, vertices

G'day!

Say I have a mouse click represented by its integer values in the window (with the window being resizable), so its domain would be (0,0) - > (current_width, current_height). Is there an easy way to 'normalise' or convert this mouse click position to a vertex in OpenGL land? i.e a point in R^2 with domain [-1,1]^2?

Eg: If the current width and height of the window was 400 and 600 respectively, and I clicked at 400,600, I'd like to easily convert that to [1,-1].

Does this functionality exist within OpenGL or will I have to write the function myself?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write the function yourself, but it's trivial:

```
x_ogl = 2.0 * (x_mouse - width / 2) / width
y_ogl = -2.0 * (y_mouse - height / 2) / height
```

The negation in the second formula is to convert from "+ve Y down" in mouse / screen coordinates to more normal cartesian of "+ve Y up".

Also, it would be more conventional to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio between X and Y coordinates with the larger axis maintaining the range [-1, 1] and the smaller axis having a smaller range.

If that's what you'd really prefer, then replace the right hand side of the outer division by `max(width, height)` in both of the two expressions above instead of as shown.

Comment: I think it had to end up being a little different. I ended up with:

`x_ogl = 1+ (x_mouse-width)*2/width` and 
`y_ogl =-1* ( (y_mouse-height)*2/height)+1)`

Thanks though. Your suggestion prompted me to work it out.

Comment: @AggressiveSneeze.  The equations I gave should be fine - see http://jsfiddle.net/8onndhuw/2/ for a (Javascript) demo